# Basic question on quadratic fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory

I'm trying to learn field theory on my own, and one of the papers I am reading has the following sentence:

> Now fix an imaginary quadratic field $K=\mathbb{Q}(-d)$, and choose $N$ with the property that the primes dividing $N$ split in $K$. Then clearly we can find an ideal $n$ with $O_K$/$n$ ≡ $\mathbb{Z}/(N)$.

Where $O_K$ is the ring of integers of $K$. I understand what this statement means but the "clearly" part is not immediately obvious to me. I just need someone to spell our exactly why that's true, to get a better sense of what those quotients actually mean.

Comment: Start with the simplest case, $d=1$ and see what happens with $N=5, 5\cdot 13,5^2\cdot 13$.

Comment: @lhf I think I am confused. If $N=5$ then it factors as $(2-i)(2+i)$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1})$, but I don't see how from that you can find an ideal. I really need this step by step, sorry...

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to show this for a prime factor of $N$. Such a $p$ will split into a product of primes $\mathfrak{p}_i$. Just chose one of them then we have 
$$O_K/\mathfrak{p}_i=\mathbb{Z}/p$$ now just take a product of all the primes dividing $N$.

Comment: Don't you need to do it for prime powers?

Comment: Hold on. English is not my native language so this may be a fundamental misunderstanding. $\mathbb{Z}/p$ is the set of all integer multiples of $p$, no?

Comment: Could you give an explicit example of this construction?